# How to get the files which have more than one lines in Shell scripting

Tags: shell, aix

I need to get the files in which it should contain more than more then 1 lines in it.

eg: file1.txt

```
756  H#001263  2869  1035  PUR  420200.00

756  H#001263  2866  1023  PUR  157500.00
```

file2.txt

```
756  S#001263  2869  7777  MCH  420200.00
```

file3.txt

```
(null file)
```

Expected output ( This should return only the file which has more than 1 lines in it )

```
file1.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for loop to determine that:

```
for i in *.txt; do [ $(wc -l < "$i") -gt 1 ] && echo "$i"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

wc -l *.txt | awk '{if ($1 > 1) print}'

the wc command gives an extra line about the total, if you don't want it, add

| sed -e '/total/d'

at the end.

Answer (score 0):

In case you know the max size of files having only 1 line, you can use the -size option of the find command, as below:

```
find . -size +37c
```